# Systems of First Order Linear Equations, finding P(t) from two given vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the vectors $x^{(1)}(t) = (t,1)$ and $x^{(2)}(t) = (t^2, 2t)$

I computed the Wronskian which is t^2. I also know that it's continuous everywhere except when t=0. But I was wondering how to solve the following question:

1) Find the systems of equations $x' = P(t) \cdot x$.

I am using Elementary Differential Equations and BVP textbook by Boyce but in nowhere does it teach me the techniques of finding $P(t)$.

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, we have:

$$x^{(1)}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}t \\1\end{pmatrix}, x^{(2)}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}t^2 \\ 2t \end{pmatrix}$$

We are asked to find:

$$P(t) = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2\\p_3 & p_4\end{pmatrix}$$

We know that:

$$x'(t) = P(t) x(t)$$

So, we can set up and solve four equations from:

$$x^{(1)}(t)' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = P(t)x^{(1)}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2\\p_3 & p_4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} t \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$x^{(2)}(t)' = \begin{pmatrix} 2t \\2\end{pmatrix} = P(t)x^{(2)}(t) =  \begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2\\p_3 &p_4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} t^2 \\ 2t\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives us the four equations:

$$t p_1 + p_2 = 1 \\ tp_3 + p_4 = 0 \\ t^2 p_1 + 2t p_2 = 2t \\ t^2 p_3 + 2 t p_4 = 2$$

Solving these yields:

$$P(t) = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 & p_2\\p_3 & p_4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -\dfrac{2}{t^2} & \dfrac{2}{t}\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that you can pretty easily solve this system and derive the solutions you started with (try it) to verify this result.

Also, look at where you found that the Wronskian is equal to zero and that result should make sense now.